# Class 'TusPhp\Tus\Client' not found

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I am using the vimeo-api library in PHP when I upload file it gives me this error. I dont know why this error is coming for me, Please look at this and let me know why this error is comming
Error: Class 'TusPhp\Tus\Client' not found
Here is my code

```
<?php
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
use Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException;
/**
 *   Copyright 2013 Vimeo
 *
 *   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *   You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *   limitations under the License.
 */
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/init.php');
if (empty($config['access_token'])) {
    throw new Exception(
        'You can not upload a file without an access token. You can find this token on your app page, or generate ' .
        'one using `auth.php`.'
    );
}
// Instantiate the library with your client id, secret and access token (pulled from dev site)
$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);
// Create a variable with a hard coded path to your file system
$file_name = "C:\Users\BASIT\Downloads\SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4";
echo 'Uploading: ' . $file_name . "\n";
try {
    // Upload the file and include the video title and description.
    $uri = $lib->upload($file_name, array(
        'name' => 'Vimeo API SDK test upload',
        'description' => "This video was uploaded through the Vimeo API's PHP SDK."
    ));
    // Get the metadata response from the upload and log out the Vimeo.com url
    $video_data = $lib->request($uri . '?fields=link');
    echo '"' . $file_name . ' has been uploaded to ' . $video_data['body']['link'] . "\n";
    // Make an API call to edit the title and description of the video.
    $lib->request($uri, array(
        'name' => 'Vimeo API SDK test edit',
        'description' => "This video was edited through the Vimeo API's PHP SDK.",
    ), 'PATCH');
    echo 'The title and description for ' . $uri . ' has been edited.' . "\n";
    // Make an API call to see if the video is finished transcoding.
    $video_data = $lib->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
    echo 'The transcode status for ' . $uri . ' is: ' . $video_data['body']['transcode']['status'] . "\n";
} catch (VimeoUploadException $e) {
    // We may have had an error. We can't resolve it here necessarily, so report it to the user.
    echo 'Error uploading ' . $file_name . "\n";
    echo 'Server reported: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
} catch (VimeoRequestException $e) {
    echo 'There was an error making the request.' . "\n";
    echo 'Server reported: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you installed it? Do you use composer? TusPhp is a dependency of the library (if I'm looking at the right github page).

Comment: @Jonnix  did not installed it with composer I just download zip from git

Comment: error is on this line  ---                                
$client = new \TusPhp\Tus\Client($base_url);

Comment: If you just installed it from git, chances are you don't have the dependencies and thus the error you're getting. you'll need to download each dependency and put them somewhere they can be found by the library / an autoloader. You can find the dependencies inside composer.json in the library's directory. Or you can save yourself a lot of effort by using composer.

Comment: I also added update composer command in cmd but TusPhp file not downloaded, Please let me know how ot download it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

hi if you using the the framework php like codeigniter then you also declare in autoload file and your path $file_name = "C:\Users\BASIT\Downloads\SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"; are not working its just apply single quotes then its working properlly